# WebDAV server that respects user accounts

Tags: linux, user-management, webdav

I’m investigating implementing a WebDAV server and all the public advice points to Apache2.

There are 2 issues with this, first it uses it’s own password file rather than the users system password and second file accesses and writes seem to be limited to the www-data user.

Is there a better way to implement this please such that the authenticated system user is used when write files? I notice that the Synology WebDAV package does this for instance.

Thanks,
Arthur